# python libraries are not imported in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio, numpy, matplotlib

My Environment in VS 2022 is Python 3.8 (same as the Python version installed on my system), I installed all packages like numpy, matplotlib, pandas and etc. using pip install, and it said successfully installed. But when I import them I get the "import (name of lib) could not be resolved from source" report. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and my solutions were:

1. check to make sure my python environment was running correctly. Mine was broken and the pip command was defaulting to my system python.
2. make sure your python environment can start from power-shell within visual studio. Mine had a privilege error that stopped the environment from loading.

If these were not the issues I would suggest adding error logs or more details because it is hard to figure out what's wrong exactly.